# How to kill the process in different group but not one-by-one?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, process

Can we just put all the processes in one group and kill that group?

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Passing `kill` a negative PID other than `-1` will send the signal to the PGID with the same absolute value.

Comment: If you are using the command, as opposed to the C function/system call, then use `--` to ensure that the negative number is not interpreted as a command option.  e.g. `kill -- -123`.

Answer (score 1):

If the processes are not in the same process group, you can't use a negative PID, but you can list more than one PID on the command line:

```
kill 1001 1010 1234 2109
```

Or if the processes have the same or similar names you can use a regular expression:

```
pkill some_prog[a-d]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for pkill -P [parent id], but that parent process has to spawn the children.